# Rails unexpected token tCOMMA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I created this object in RSpec. I am getting the error `unexpected token tCOMMA` at second `},` Any idea why i am getting this error?

```
   let(:test) {
     { abc:
       [{ bde:
         { attribute1: 170.0,
           attribute2: '2016-12-14',
           attribute3: 'self entered',
           attribute4: 'high',
           attribute5:
             { attribute6: 'low',
               attribute7: false,
               attribute8: nil,
               attribute9: 129,
               attribute0: 'mg/dL'},
             { attribute11: 'moderate',
               attribute12: false,
               attribute13: 130,
               attribute14: 159,
               attribute15: 'mg/dL' }, # getting error unexpected token tCOMMA
             { attribute16: 'high',
               attribute17: true,
               attribute18: 160,
               attribute19: nil,
               attribute20: 'mg/dL' }
         }
       }]
     }}
```

Comment: if you format your code properly you'll see that `attribute5`should be an array

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `attribute5` in your code is an array, not a hash. Try this code:

```
   let(:test) {
            {
              abc: [{
               bde: {
                 attribute1: 170.0,
                 attribute2: '2016-12-14',
                 attribute3: 'self entered',
                 attribute4: 'high',
                 attribute5: [{
                     attribute6: 'low',
                     attribute7: false,
                     attribute8: nil,
                     attribute9: 129,
                     attribute0: 'mg/dL'
                 },
                 {
                     attribute11: 'moderate',
                     attribute12: false,
                     attribute13: 130,
                     attribute14: 159,
                     attribute15: 'mg/dL'
                 },
                 {
                     attribute16: 'high',
                     attribute17: true,
                     attribute18: 160,
                     attribute19: nil,
                     attribute20: 'mg/dL'
                 }]
              }
            }]
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but when i run Rspec i get error `undefined method `key?' for #<Array:0x007fa4946d9260>`